# Obtaining clients IP address in GWT and Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a need to capture IP address of the client in my GWT/GAE (Java) application. Since GAE does not support full set of java.net APIs I cannot do code such as snippet below. Can anyone suggest reliable way of achieving the same?

```
for (final Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
    final NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
    for (final Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
        final InetAddress ip = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
        if (!ip.isLoopbackAddress() && !ip.isLinkLocalAddress() && !ip.isAnyLocalAddress()) {
                return ip.getHostAddress().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

For Python version one can do:

```
os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

or

```
String ip = self.request.remote_addr;
```

But what would be a Java equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK - got it. In your Servlet which should extend `RemoteServiceServlet` do this:

```
final String ip = getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are behind a proxy, for example, if you use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse you could find useful this:

```
this.getThreadLocalRequest().getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR")
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you want the IP address you might want to use getRemoteAddr instead of getRemoteHost.

```
String ip   = getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteAddr();
String host = getThreadLocalRequest().getRemoteHost();
```

- **getRemoteAddr** gives you the internet protocol (IP) address of the client.
- **getRemoteHost** gives you the fully qualified name of the client, the IP if the host name is empty.

See the Oracle Javadoc:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29

Comment: Saw that, didn't mean to be presumptuous. Just wanted to point out the difference between getRemoteAddr and getRemoteHost.